# Preparation of cocktails using whiskey

Tags: whiskey, cocktails, preparation-for-drinking

I'm a whiskey enthusiast and I want to try making cocktails using whiskey (Normally I use chilled water or Ice cubes, but some whiskeys have an obnoxious smell). I have tried **bourbon (JD, Jim Beam)** with **Fanta** and it tasted good. **Is it possible to use some cold drinks/soft drinks together with whiskey** (like Red Label, Black & White, Teachers, etc, even Signature)?

Looking forward to any helpful suggestion!

Answer (score 8):

Whisky/whiskey and soda is a drink that's been popular since the 19th century. In the basic form it is very simple, but there are many possible variations (see, for example, [these eight recipes](https://www.chivas.com/en-EN/latest-from-chivas/8-whisky-highball-recipes-you-need-to-try) from Chivas Regal.

Smokey whisky and Cola (which is usually called a "Smokey Cokey") is my personal favourite.

Answer (score 3):

For a two-ingredient cocktail involving a cold pre-made drink you could mix whiskey with your favorite sweetened canned cold brew coffee for a quick Irish coffee.

If you're willing to buy a couple additional versatile liquors you can build up a bar that would allow you to mix up some fun cocktails. If you like a slightly bitter and refreshing drink, a bottle of Campari and some sweet vermouth unleashes the [Boulevardier](https://www.liquor.com/recipes/boulevardier/). (Drifting from your question a bit, if you sub gin for the whiskey and you've got a [Negroni](https://www.seriouseats.com/negroni-cocktail-recipe-gin-campari-vermouth).)

Hold the Campari and add a couple dashes of Angostura bitters and you have a [Manhattan](https://www.seriouseats.com/cocktails-manhattan-recipe).

Hold the sweet vermouth and add some sugar and you can make an [Old Fashioned](https://www.seriouseats.com/traditional-old-fashioned-recipe).

Lots of fun to be had adding just a couple additional bottles to your liquor cabinet!

Comment: And if you use Scotch rather than American whiskey in the Manhattan recipe, you have a Rob Roy (see for example, The Spruce Eats: https://www.thespruceeats.com/rob-roy-cocktail-recipe-759335)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes like to make a semblance of a blue lagoon

### Recipe

1. Whiskey - 50ml
2. Blue curacao - 20ml
3. Sprite - 150ml
4. Fruit to taste
5. Ice - 50 - 200g.

**The color that will turn out, I have not seen anywhere :)**

Answer (score 2):

If you widen out your choice to include Scotch whiskies, there are a huge range of cocktails that will work with both the delicate flavours of a lowland whisky and the powerful peatiness of Islay malts.

I would even recommend a Talisker Hot Toddy for when you have a sore throat:

- Lemon
- Honey
- Hot water
- Talisker